# Find out if post was just updated on post edit screen

Tags: admin, actions, notices

Is it possible to add an [admin_notice](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) to the *post.php* edit screen in the admin– only if the post was just updated.

```
function my_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
        // Check if the post was just updated...
        echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
            <p>This is my custom post-was-just-updated admin notice.</p>
        </div>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

Comment: Wordpress already adds a "Post Updated" admin notice when a post is updated, so not sure I understand the question. But you're best bet it to use `$_POST` to detect the presence of a form input, usually the name of the submit button is a good start (i.e. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //... }`)

Comment: Yeah it would have been more constructive to ask _How_ does wordpress know that the post has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking in WP Core. When you update a post it actually takes you back to the edit posts screen (*post.php*) with a GET parameter of `message=1`. And then it erases that parameter from the url with javascript quickly. So you can find out if posts were uploaded in a plugin by checking:

```
if ($_GET['message'] == 1) {
  // do something because the post was just updated
}
```